# Why is there an extra percent sign after the output?

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm learning fork() function under linux recently. I wrote a program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int p1, p2;
    while((p1 = fork()) == -1);
    if(p1 == 0)
        printf("b");
    else{
        while((p2 = fork()) == -1);
        if(p2 == 0)
            printf("c");
        else
            printf("a");
    }
}
```

After I compiled and run it, I got a unexpected percent sign.

[image]

But if I add \n after those letters, the percent sign disappears.

[image]

Is there anyone knows the reason?

And I have another question. Every time I reran the program, I got the same answer. It always shows "acb". The order is always the same. Why?

Comment: *`while((p1 = fork()) == -1);`* looks  a lot like Android's [Rage Against the Cage](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rage+Against+the+Cage+Android)

Comment: in C, the function: `fork()` prototype is brought visible by the combination of the two header files: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <unistd.h>`.  Without those two header files, the code is relying on  the default types (usually `int`, but not necessarily)  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.

Comment: regarding: `while((p1 = fork()) == -1);`  Most likely, if `fork()` fails, it will continue to fail.  This is NOT a valid/reliable way to check for an error in the call to `fork()`

Comment: when a parent process forks a child process, it should always call `wait()` or `waitpid()` so that it does not exit before the child exits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your shell (zsh) added it to indicate the output did not end with a newline character.

To get rid of it, just end your output with a `\n`.

As to the other question, it's not deterministic. If you ran it elsewhere or enough times you might get different results. But it's an illustration of why synchronization problems can be so hard to find, because things can seem to run the same (almost) all the time.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Note: The (mostly) predictable ordering may be because they're running in a virtual machine (note the VirtualBox in the prompt). If the VM is only simulating one processor, then only one process actually runs at a time, and it would make sense for the parent's time slice to continue after the `fork` long enough for it to perform the output, so it always ends up outputting parent first (the one that outputs `a`). As for `c` preceding `b`, the scheduler may (as implementation detail) tend to prioritize the last launched child (leading to `c` being the next output); that's just a guess though.

Comment: Also note: If you want to have all the output on a single line, you should have the parent process call `wait(2)` (2 being the man page section, not the argument) twice, then `printf("\n");` so the newline is only output once, and only after all other output. If you want to keep the output unpredictable, you'd also need to add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("a");` but before the `wait` calls, otherwise when `stdout` is line or block buffered (the default), the parent process will always delay flushing buffers until the child processes have exited, so `a` will end up predictably last.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. correctly checks the returned value from `fork()`
2. correctly includes the necessary header files
3. correctly waits for the child processes to exit before the parent process exits
4. still does not terminate output strings with '\n' so (in this case) the output is not displayed on the terminal until after the process exits.
5. uses the proper typing for pid variables
6. uses one of the two valid signatures for `main()`

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     // printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>    // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <sys/types.h> // pid_t
#include <unistd.h>    // fork()
#include <sys/wait.h>  // wait()

int main( void )
{
    pid_t p1;
    pid_t p2;

    p1 = fork();
    switch( p1 )
    {
        case -1:
            perror( "first fork failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            break;

        case 0:  // child 1
            printf("child 1");
            exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
            break;

        default:  // parent
            p2 = fork();
            switch( p2 )
            {
                case -1:
                    perror( "second fork failed" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    break;

                case 0: // child 2
                    printf("child 2");
                    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("parent");
                    while( wait( NULL ) != -1 );
                    break;
            }  // end switch 2
    } // end switch 1
}
```

a typical run of the code results in:

```
child 2child 1parent
```