# Character '%' gets appended to output in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am executing some simple C++ code in VSCode on a MAC + code runner.
There are no warnings or compile errors, but in the terminal output window there is this annoying '%' symbol appended, as you can see below:

[image]

What causes it, and how can i get rid of it?

Comment: Interesting. Probably the terminal prompting for the next input. What happens when you end the output with a newline?

Comment: Side note `pow(2,x)` is much quicker (and more accurate since floating point math tends to get a little fuzzy) with bitshifting: `1 << x`

Comment: _"how can i get rid of it?"_ - Add `<< '\n';` last to your last `std::cout` line and see if that helps

Comment: Similar to ["%" gets added to the standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71607916/c-gets-added-to-the-standard-output), but the resolution of that question is "less likely to help future readers" (according to the close reason -- not sure I personally buy that ;) ), so I suppose linking to it is not as much help as I'd hope. *(I've seen other posts on this topic, but cannot find them now. Maybe the rest ended up deleted?)*

Comment: There's [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270945/percent-sign-at-the-end-of-the-output-of-python-script) [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932577/why-is-there-an-extra-percent-sign-after-the-output) that aren't about C++ but are nevertheless about the same behavior. And ultimately the behavior is being caused by your shell, not the C++ stuff itself, so that's probably to be expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse+bold `%` indicates a lack of `'\n'` at the end of the line. `zsh` has this to let you see unterminated lines in a command's output. You can get rid of it by using `std::endl` like so:

```
std::cout<< z << std::endl;
// or
std::cout<< z << '\n';
```

Keep in mind that `std::endl` flushes the output buffer and `'\n'` doesn't.

---

From [zsh doc](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html):

- `PROMPT_SP <D>`
  Attempt to preserve a partial line (i.e. a line that did not end with a newline) that would otherwise be covered up by the command prompt due to the `PROMPT_CR` option. This works by outputting some cursor-control characters, including a series of spaces, that should make the terminal wrap to the next line when a partial line is present (note that this is only successful if your terminal has automatic margins, which is typical).

  When a partial line is preserved, by default **you will see an inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line**: a `%` for a normal user or a `#` for root. If set, the shell parameter `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` can be used to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.

  NOTE: if the `PROMPT_CR` option is not set, enabling this option will have no effect. This option is on by default.